# webpack dynamic import - how to load multiple resources

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, module

Using the `require.ensure` mechanism, it is possible to load multiple resources and put them in the same chunk, like this:

```
let promise;

export function loadLib() {
    if (!promise) {
        promise = new Promise(resolve => {
            require.ensure(
                [],
                require => {
                    require('some-lib/dist/some-lib.css');
                    require('./some-other-stuff');
                    resolve(require('some-lib'));
                },
                'lib.some-filename'
            );
        });
    }
    return promise;
}
```

Lately, I use the dynamic import mechanism where possible, e.g.

```
System.import(/* webpackChunkName: 'component.MyComponent' */ './MyComponent')`
```

Typically in combination with e.g. `react-loadable` or react 16 lazy.

So: how to load multiple resources with dynamic `import` statement into a single chunk?
Or: What's the best strategy for bundling multiple resources into the same chunk when using dynamic imports?

The focus is to bundle the files together, not to have a custom filename (I know that in some scenarios, like c-r-a, `System.import()` is discouraged and just `import()` is recommended, which might not support the webpackChunkName syntax.)

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: I believe I used proxy modules, e.g. a module that statically imports the required set of other modules, which is then itself imported dynamically.